# Selenium C# send save command in ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open the save file dialog (by doing Ctrl+s) in Chrome while viewing a pdf file. What I currently have doesn't seem to be sending any keystrokes, as nothing is happening. I don't need to worry about what I do with the save file dialog once it's open, I just need to open it. This is what I have now:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")));
action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control).SendKeys("s").KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control);
action.Build();
action.Perform();
```

Comment: Keys combinations won't work with `Chrome`. Try `Firefox` instead

Comment: The application needs to be tested in Chrome.  Is there any other way to save a pdf?

Comment: You can try to use `String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();` to save file content as string, but I'm not sure

Comment: You could try a key chord combination.

Comment: or how about - action.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "s");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using Windows Forms to do it, which I was going to do anyway to interact with the save file dialog, so I'm not worried about the dependencies. I directed Chrome to view the pdf and then sent a Ctrl+s command.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Robot API, once the tab is opened:

```
Robot key = new Robot();
            key.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            key.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            key.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            key.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

This should work. Make sure that the browser is not minimized.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I was using C#.  The Robot class won't work for me.